# Error when sending both an email and a fax with the same SMTP (C#)

Tags: c#, email, smtp, fax

I am currently working on a routine that automatically generates a Text from some predefined Settings, and should send that Text either as an Email or a Fax - or even both.

Code looks like this:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(Properties.Settings.Default.SmtpServer)
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true
};

if (IsMail)
{
    var sendMail = "current users email";
    using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(sendMail, this.EmailAddress))
    {
    mm.Subject = this.Subject;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.MailBody))
    {
        mm.Body = this.MailBody.Replace("\n\n", "<br><br>");
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
    }

    if (this.IsCcMail)
        mm.CC.Add(sendMail);

    foreach (var a in Attachments)
        mm.Attachments.Add(a);

    smtp.Send(mm);
    }   
}

if (IsFax)
{
    var formatedFaxNo = this.CountryPhoneCode + FaxNo.TrimStart('0');
    using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("current users email", formatedFaxNo + "@fax"))
    {
        mm.Subject = this.Subject;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.MailBody))
        {
            mm.Body = this.MailBody.Replace("\n\n", "<br><br>");
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        }
        if (IsCcFax)
            mm.CC.Add("current users fax" + "@fax");

        if (ShowMessageYesNo(Translator.WouldYouLikeToSendTheFaxWithACoverSheet) != System.Windows.MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            mm.Headers.Add("EMPTYBODYTEXT", "1");
        else
        {
            var faxBody = Properties.Resources.FaxTemplate.ToString();
            mm.Body = string.Format(faxBody,
            Translator.Fax, formatedFaxNo,
            Translator.From, "current users name",
            Translator.Subject, this.Subject,
            Translator.Date, DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
            this.MailBody?.Replace("\n\n","<br><br>"));
        }
        foreach (var a in Attachments)
            mm.Attachments.Add(a);

        smtp.Send(mm);
    }
}
```

If I want to send both an email and a Fax, I get a SMTP exception at the time the Fax is supposed to be sent - the Email is successfully sent before.
The Error only reads

> "Error sending Mail"

Which is not really helpful.

**So far I've tried**:
Sending two mails instead of a Mail and a Fax - works as intended;
Sending two Faxes likewise - works as intended;
Changing the Order and sending the Fax before the Mail - The Fax gets sent, but I get the SMTP exception on sending the mail;
Disposing the SmtpClient after sending the Mail and creating a new one for the Fax - does not change anything;

To me it seems like there is an issue with the SMTP Server I'm trying to send stuff from, but I'm currently not able to change anything about the Server.

Does anyone here have any further suggestions what I could try to fix that Issue?

Comment: Which line throws the exception? What is the **exact** message?

Comment: Have you checked InnerException?

Comment: the line "smtp.Send(mm)" throws the Exception, and the Message is "Error sending Mail". I've located the inner Exception though, it reads "One of the Streams has already been used and can not be resetted" so the problem might just be with the attachments